# C: multiple subprocesses reading from the same file

Tags: c, subprocess, parent-child

I am trying to read from a file with size filesize with n subprocesses. My question is this: if filesize%subprocesses != 0, how do I distribute the filesize so that the entirety of the file is being read? My idea was to have one of the subprocesses read a little less than the others, but I'm not sure how to do that. Here is my code, subprocesses is the number of children I fork().

```
fstat(infile, &filestatus);
filesize = filestatus.st_size;
fs = (filesize + (subprocesses /2))/subprocesses;
```

The issue with this type of rounding is that as I change subprocesses, I don't read infile correctly. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `subprocesses > 1` and `filesize > 0`, and both are of integral type, all you need to do is

```
 if (filesize % subprocesses == 0)
 {
      fs = filesize/subprocesses;
 }
 else
 {
     fs = filesize/(subprocesses-1);     //  amount to be read by all except the last subprocess

     fs_last = filesize % (subprocesses - 1)    //  amount to be read by the last subprocess
 }
```

Mathematically, `fs_last = filesize - (subprocesses - 1)*fs` will do the same thing - that's a property of integer arithmetic.

Your next problem will be communicating to each sub-process how much to read.    Or ensuring that the last subprocess knows it is the last one (so it doesn't try to read `fs` characters instead of `fs_last`).

Comment: Peter I owe you one! Yeah, now I'm stuck on how to let the last subprocess know that its the last subprocess? I'm using a for loop to fork n subprocesses, so how do i do that?

Comment: For each call of `fork()`, you should be checking the return value.   The forked process receives a return value of zero, the parent receives a positive value if forking succeeded, and negative value if forking failed.    The last subprocess will be characterised by `fork()` returning zero in the last iteration of the loop.

Comment: when the code calls `exec*` to execute a child process (all the sub processes are child processes) include the number-of-byte-to-read and the offset-to-first-byte-to-read as two of the parameters passed to the sub process.  As a second option, each process tries to read the same number bytes, the last sub process will hit EOF, which should be coded to stop that process from trying to read any more bytes.